# npm install failing on npm v6 but passing on v8 (latest)

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install a package which I created (let's say `abc`) and getting the below error

Stacktrace:

```
$ npm i -g abc                                                       
/<home>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.10/bin/abc -> /<home>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.10/lib/node_modules/abc/src/bin/runner.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /<home>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.10/lib/node_modules/abc/bin.js
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/<home>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.10/lib/node_modules/abc/bin.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /<home>/.npm/_logs/2022-08-05T07_58_00_703Z-debug.log
```

The issue is happening on npm v6 (I am using 6.14.17) while it is able to install the package with v8 (latest)

The changes I made in the version that I published is have a very basic script and put it in `bin`.

```
// package.json snippet

  "license": "xyz",
  "bin": {
    "my-package": "./src/bin/runner.js",
    "setup": "./bin.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
```

```
// package.json snippet (older version which is getting installed correctly with v6 as well

  "license": "xyz",
  "bin": {
    "my-package": "./src/bin/runner.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
-- root-folder
   -- src
     -- bin
       -- runner.js
   -- bin.js
   -- package.json
```

Things I tried:

- Different versions of node - failing for all with npm v6
- Working for same node versions (v12 and above) for npm v8 (latest)
- The same code was working on npm v6 with npm link (before publishing while testing)
- Tried older versions published of the package and they were installed as expected so something in this release is causing the issue
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install using --force
- npm install with and without `-g`

Comment: So this just got sorted for me. There was an issue with publishing the release. The dist folder apparently didn't have that file. But the issue was happening just for v6 because of an npm issue. With npm > 6, the error wasn't been raised (suppressed ) and package was installed successfully while for v6 the error was failing the installation. Will raise an issue on npm for this to be able to catch the error in latest version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command  `npm i --froce`

This should bypass some problems in your dependencies!

Comment: Didn't solve the issue :(